# How to take sample of data from very unbalanced DataFrame so as to not lose too many '1' for Machine Learning in Python?

Tags: machine-learning, python, sampling, predictive-models, subsampling

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below with ID and Target variable (for machine learning model).

- My DataFrame is really large and unbalanced.
- I need to make sampling on my DataFrame because it is really large
- Balancing the DataFrame looks like this:

  - 99.60% - 0
  - 0.40 % - 1

    | ID | TARGET |
    | --- | --- |
    | 111 | 1 |
    | 222 | 1 |
    | 333 | 0 |
    | 444 | 1 |
    | ... | ... |

My question is: How to sample the data, so as not to lose too many ones (target = 1), which are very rare anyway, in the next step, of course, I will add the remaining variables and perform over sampling, nevertheless at the begining i need to take smample of data.

How can I do that in Python ?

Comment: What for do you want to sample the data?

Comment: Tim, are too big to work on in a jupyter notebook

Comment: But what do you need to use the data for? There are ways of working with data that does not fit into RAM.

Comment: I will use this data to build machine learning model :) Tim - do you know how to take sample from my data to not lose too many '1' ? :)

Comment: What is your data? Why is it unbalanced? What problem are you trying to solve with it? "How not to loose 1" is not a problem, you could take all the 1's and random 0's, but you would potentially end up with garbage data leading to useless results. You need to first tell us more about the data and the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: So, in your opinion if I take all the 1's and random 0's I will have useless results? Why? it is interesting... Do you think that for example Random Sampling could be better or Stratify Sampling ?

Comment: You need to give us more detail about your data and what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: Tim, I need to create sample from my dataset